# Как реализовать добавление нового пользователя другим пользователем (admin) в rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Здравствуйте, есть пользователь с правами админа, для него на сайте есть кнопочка для добавления нового пользователя. Эта кнопка вызывает такую форму:

```
= simple_form_for User.new do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true
    = f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)
    = f.input :password_confirmation, required: true
    = f.input :login, required: true
    = f.label :date_of_birth, class:"control-group"
    = f.text_field :date_of_birth, class:"form-control datepicker", required: true
    = f.input :country, as: :select, collection: ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES
    = f.input :city, required: true
    = f.input :address, required: true
    = f.input :avatar
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Sign up"
```

Для авторизации использую гем Devise. Проблема в том, что при добавлении пользователя таким образом выскакивает сообщение "You are already signed in." и новый юзер не добавляется.

Код контроллера

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "User was successufly created"
      redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Роуты:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tags
  resources :answers do
    member do
      put "like" => "answers#upvote"
      put "unlike" => "answers#downvote"
    end
  end
  resources :questions do
    member do
      put "like" => "questions#upvote"
      put "unlike" => "questions#downvote"
    end
  end
  get 'home/index'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks", registrations: 'registrations' }
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
  resources :users, except: [:show]
  root 'home#index'

end
```

Comment: Код контроллера, который добавляет пользователя покажите. И роуты тоже.

Comment: @MAXOPKA Добавил

Comment: Chrevatov есть предположение, что экшен `create` из вашего контроллера не отрабатывает, так как метод `devise_for` добавляет маршрут, в который попадает содержимое формы. В маршрутах вызовите `devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "callbacks", registrations: 'registrations' }`  после объявления всех маршрутов